# Tutorial on setting up GWT-Validation Framework for a simple app?

Tags: gwt

I'm looking to setup the GWT-Validation Framework (client side for now) in our application, but I'm not clear from the docs what pieces I need and what goes where?

We are using GWT 2.1 and MVP. I have the inherits entry for Validation in the gwt.xml, but what goes actually goes into the View, Activity, etc... I'm not aware of any tutorials available.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Aftermath:
At the time when I was trying to use it, GWT 2.1 wasn't compatible with the GWT-Validation framework. After doing more reading I found this out.  I don't know if that is still the case.**

Comment: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html, go through 'Large scale application development and MVP, Part I', 'Large scale application development and MVP, Part II' Its pretty clear. If you dont get any concepts, you can ask for specific parts.  Dont think you will need any othat tutorial than this.

Comment: Well it appears that GWT 2.1 isn't compatible with GWT-Validation 1.0. I'm getting this error when trying to run my code: gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/constraints/NotGwtCompatibleValidator.java'. Has anyone seen this problem before and is there a workaround or fix available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the validation framework in GWT and not the [gwt-validation library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/)? If that's the case, here is a page that describes how you can do bean validation: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation. If you are actually referring to the gwt-validation library, here is a page that describes how to use it:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/wiki/ConceptOfOperations

Comment: Yes I read that, but having a tutorial or some more in depth example code would help more. It's the GWT Validation Framework (GWTVF) that I"m referring to by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that gives some information about the GWT Validation Framework, GWT-Validator and the authors solution, the GWT-Validation library.  It is a good synopsis of the issues and why he wrote the new library with some code snippets.

[The GWT Validation Library.](http://gwt-vl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The link appears to be stale :-(